# Using BouncyCastle In Talend

Tags: bouncycastle, talend

I'm looking for guidance on importing BouncyCastle for use in a Talend project. I need to open a privatekey in PEM format and use it to sign a nonce in order to fetch an auth token.

I can add the jar to the build path, but not sure how to import it into my Routines code. I tried another technique, but facing an error using the SHA512withRSA algorithm. I have working Java code to achieve this, I'm just trying to port it into my Talend workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the routine and select `Edit Routines Libraries`

[image]

Add your jar, and check `If the library is required` to include the jar in the build.

[image]